# How can i get value from textarea and print it vertically?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my array for example from the first textarea:

```
$names=array('Abcd','Efgh','Jklm');
```

And for now this is my script:

```
function myFunction() {
    var stringArray = document.getElementById('edno').value.split('\n');
    document.getElementById("dve").innerHTML = stringArray;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="first">
    <textarea id="edno"></textarea>
    <p>Click the button</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"></button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <textarea id="dve">

    </textarea>
 <script type="text/javascript">Here is my Script<script>
</div>

</body>
```

I want to print the value, splited by `,`, char by char, vertically.
Example of desired result when input is `abcd,efgh,jklm`:
[image]

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I have just edited my post

Comment: By vertically, do you mean rotated 90 degrees? Or do you want the text to print from top to bottom, character by character?

Comment: I want to print them from top to bottom char by char

Comment: Judging from your image, what would happen if the second provided string has 5 characters, and the other two have 4 characters?

Comment: It will have 5 column with 4 lines i think,just the last column will be with only one symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value, split it character by character and then print it with a line break `\n` if you will use in an input element, or with `<br>` if you gonna use another kind of element.

The code below shows that.

```js
function myFunction() {
    let stringArray = document.getElementById('edno').value.split("");
    let txtResult = document.getElementById("dve");
    txtResult.value = "";
    for (var char of stringArray){ 
      var character = char + "\n";
      txtResult.value += character;
    }
}
```

```css
#dve{
  height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <textarea id="edno"></textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <textarea id="dve"></textarea>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
To help you with what you commented here's a possible solution:
It's much harder, because you need to iterate in the loop of characters in a very different way.

To avoid problem with different rows/columns sizes I needed to get the longest word length, as you can see in the code in the var called `biggerLength`

Please, see the code, any question you have about iteration, post in the comments.

```js
function myFunction() {
    let txtResult = document.getElementById("dve");
    let str = document.getElementById('edno').value;
    let strArray = [];
    txtResult.value = "";

    if (str.indexOf(",") > -1){
      strArray = str.split(",");
      let sortedStrArray = [...strArray].sort((a,b) => a.length < b.length); 
      //copy the original array to not mess with it, then sort bigger to smallest length
      let biggerLength = sortedStrArray[0].length;
      
      for (var i = 0; i < biggerLength; i++){
        let columnStr = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++){
          let chars = strArray[j];
          let char = chars[i];
          if (char != null){
            columnStr += char;
          }else{
            columnStr += " ";
          }
        }
        txtResult.value += columnStr + "\n";
      }
      
    } else {
      strArray = str.split("");
      for (var char of strArray){ 
        txtResult.value += char + "\n";
      }
    }   
}
```

```css
#dve{
  height: 200px;
  width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <textarea id="edno" >abcd,efgh,jklm</textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <textarea id="dve"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: The first example is 90% of this what i search.For example if i input this : ABCD,EFGH,JKLM .. i want to output it like A.. B(under A),C(under B),D(under C) so E right next to A,F(under E and next to B),G(Under F and next to C) and etc.

Comment: I have just added image of what i search for

Comment: Ok, it's harder, but I'll edit my answer in a few minutes and then I tell you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy the text from the first textarea to the second you can do it simply like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var valueOfFirstTextarea = document.getElementById('edno').value;
  document.getElementById("dve").innerHTML = valueOfFirstTextarea;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <textarea id="edno"></textarea>
  <p>Click the button</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div id="second">
  <textarea id="dve"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what i search but it helps me a lot too,thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the values vertically, split all the values by space and append that with `<br>` and append the same to

`elements = ['Abcd','Efgh','Jklm'];
document.getElementById("dve").innerHTML = elements.join('</br>')`

This will print all the elements in vertical in the innerHTML of dev element.